# How to run a python script as a subprocess inside Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, subprocess, google-cloud-functions, serverless

```
import subprocess 
import os

def execute(): 
    code = "def Solution():\n\tprint('Hello')\n\nSolution()\n"
    f = open('/tmp/Solution.py','w')
    f.write(code+'\n')
    f.close() 
    s = subprocess.check_output("python /tmp/Solution.py", shell = True) 
    return s
```

I am calling execute function from the cloud function handler. This works locally but on gcloud subprocess.check_output returns with non zero exit code.

Is it because gcloud runtime environment cannot find python interpreter? In either case, how can I do something like this? What am I missing here? I don't have much information in the logs so I am stuck.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using backslashes in the file path? Cloud Functions runs Linux, and the file paths will use forward slashes, e.g. /tmp/Solution.py

Answer (score 0):

You have to expect your function as being deployed into a container that includes, in your case, a Python runtime. You can not assume that your cloud function includes a shell also. Therefore is not recommended to use `subprocess` in your python code.

Comment: subprocess.check_output("echo Hello", shell = True). This line of code worked fine.The problem was only with python. The cloud function I am using does have a python runtime so I thought this should have worked too, but the lack of error messages makes it difficult to debug.

Comment: I would suggest to use Google Cloud Run.